# How to detect failed downloads using yfinance

Tags: python, yfinance

I am using the API yfinance: https://github.com/ranaroussi/yfinance

With the simple code below:

```
data = yf.download("A AA AAA Z LOL KE QP")
```

I got the following output:

```
[*********************100%***********************]  7 of 7 completed

2 Failed downloads:
- LOL: 1d data not available for startTime=-2208988800 and endTime=1621954979. Only 100 years worth of day granularity data are allowed to be fetched per request.
- QP: 1d data not available for startTime=-2208988800 and endTime=1621954979. Only 100 years worth of day granularity data are allowed to be fetched per request.
```

I would like to know how can I detect in my code that "LOL" and "QP" failed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the code where the 'error' is thrown in the yfinance package. This is not an actual error so you might want to override the function `download` which is quite big.

```py
if shared._ERRORS:
    print('\n%.f Failed download%s:' % (
    len(shared._ERRORS), 's' if len(shared._ERRORS) > 1 else ''))
    # print(shared._ERRORS)
    print("\n".join(['- %s: %s' %
    v for v in list(shared._ERRORS.items())]))
```

---

## Edit

---

If found a way to get the failed download:
simply import the `shared.py` file and get the `ERRORS` dict.
This dict stores the last errors of the download method. It is reset before a download so it is accessible right after it.

Simply use the following code:

```py
import yfinance.shared as shared

data = yf.download("A AA AAA Z LOL KE QP")
print(list(shared._ERRORS.keys()))
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it is working perfectly :)

Comment: I don't know who you are, but I love you.

Answer (score 0):

After playing a little bit more with the data output I found a non-elegant way of checking for failed values, for example for the element "LOL":

```
all(pd.isna(v) for v in dict(data.Close["LOL"]).values())
```

It check if all values are nan for the closing price.

This method is working, but not optimal I think, there might be a better and simpler way of doing it. Lets hope someone find it :)